# Convert string to float in dataframe using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, type-conversion

I am new to python and doing practice with pandas. In my data frame there's a column called NET_REVENUE and its type is string. I'm trying to convert it into float for further analysis.

However, when I run following code it gives feedback I don't really understand. 
I am positive that there were no missing value in the original column. Obviously some have been converted successfully into float. But 2918 out of 4732 are not.

Can someone help please?

```
sep_IM_2019['NET_REVENUE_numeric'] = pd.to_numeric(sep_IM_2019['NET_REVENUE'], errors='coerce')
```

> /Users/Leo/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
>   """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

```
sep_IM_2019.NET_REVENUE_numeric.isnull().sum()
#2918


    sep_IM_2019.NET_REVENUE_numeric
8       NaN
46      NaN
56      NaN
62      NaN
71      NaN
         ..
76472   NaN
76476   NaN
76503   NaN
76505   NaN
76510   NaN
Name: NET_REVENUE_numeric, Length: 4732, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help you understand the warning -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627316/8231447

As for converting to a float - I'm not sure whether you want to run to_numeric, or call .astype(float) on the series

```
sep_IM_2019["NET_REVENUE_numeric"] = ]sep_IM_2019['NET_REVENUE'].astype(float).
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @Adoni5, I actually wonder where's the difference b/w to_numeric and astype in terms of result we could get.

Answer (score 0):

You used `errors='coerce'`, so when it doesn't manage to convert to float it gives you a NaN instead of raising an error.

Try to run `to_numeric` without that parameter to see what's the problem exactly. It's likely that some of your strings can't be converted. Take a closer look at them:

```
sep_IM_2019.loc[8,'NET_REVENUE']
```

should be the first string having that problem if I believe your list.

Comment: It turns out values that couldn't be converted are 'currency', with auto-generated 1000 comma, in the csv file. After changing them all into 'general' in csv, I am able to use either to_numeric or astype to convert all the values into floats with no NaN. However, I still get the same waring as above:             

/Users/Leo/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead...

Comment: The warning has nothing to do with the conversion. It's because at some point you've made a copy of your dataframe without saying you wanted it to be a whole new dataframe, so to speak. Without your code I can't tell you where.